Box layout shrinks when the other layouts expand
I have a column layout with a box layout of weight(1f) and then a LazyColumn with fillmaxwidth() and wrapcontentheight() inside it. Whenever I add an element in the LazyColumn, the LazyColumn expands and shrinks the box layout, I want the LazyColumn to expand without changing the size of the box layout. That is the LazyColumn should expand outside outside the screen, without giving the LazyColumn a fixed height. The box layout cannot be in wrapcontent as the box layout will be holding a webview inside it, if I once intialize the size it cannot be changed. I would prefer the box layout having all the space it can.
@Composable
fun Greeting() {
    val focus = FocusRequester()
    var list by remember {
        mutableStateOf(listOf<String>())
    }

    Scaffold(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                title = {
                    Text(
                        text = "Title",
                        fontSize = 18.sp,
                        fontFamily = FontFamily.SansSerif
                    )
                },
                navigationIcon = {
                    IconButton(onClick = { logState("Title -> ${_title.value}") }) {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = Icons.Default.ArrowBack,
                            contentDescription = "Back Icon",
                            tint = Color.White
                        )
                    }
                },
                actions = {
                    IconButton(onClick = {
                        logState("Add Attachment Pressed")
                        list = list + "Hello"
                    }) {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = Icons.Default.Add,
                            contentDescription = "Add Attachment",
                            tint = Color.White
                        )
                    }
                    IconButton(onClick = { logState("Save Pressed") }) {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = Icons.Default.Check,
                            contentDescription = "Save Button",
                            tint = Color.White
                        )
                    }
                    IconButton(onClick = {
                        logState("Edit Pressed")
                        isEditMode = !isEditMode
                        focus.requestFocus()
                    }
                    ) {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = Icons.Default.Edit,
                            contentDescription = "Edit Icon",
                            tint = Color.White
                        )
                    }
                },
                colors = TopAppBarDefaults.smallTopAppBarColors(
                    containerColor = Color.Blue,
                    titleContentColor = Color.White
                )
            )
        }
    ) { paddingValues ->
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(paddingValues)
        ) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .weight(1f)
                    .focusable(true)
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = "TEXT INSIDE BOX",
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
                )
            }
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .wrapContentHeight()
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = "Attachments",
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .wrapContentSize(),
                    fontSize = 15.sp
                )
                Text(
                    text = text = "${list.size}",
                    modifier = Modifier.wrapContentSize()
                )
            }

            LazyColumn(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .wrapContentHeight()
            ) {
                items(list) {
                    Text(text = it)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

fun logState(state: String) {
    Log.d("TEST", state)
}

I tried verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()) but it throws an error. It says that the LazyColumn could be of infinte length. I switched the LazyColumn to a column layout, and the same problem occurs. When i give a max height for the LazyColumn, the elements can be scrolled only in side the height, I want to be like a list view which can be scrollable the outer scroll and not by the scroll of the LazyColumn.

"I would prefer the box layout having all the space it can." -- That means the entire height, so there will never be any space left for the LazyColumn. Did you mean instead "all the space it needs"? Then you could just remove the weight from the Box and the fillMaxSize from the Text composable. The Box will take as much space as its content needs, and the remaining space will be taken by the list.
